# Connecting to Redis cluster (in Docker) with Python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, redis-cluster

I'm setting up a highly available Redis cluster (with Sentinels), and need to write data to it in Python. However, I don't know which hostname to use when connecting from Python, and I am also receiving "Connection refused".

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:latest
ADD sentinel.conf /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
RUN chown redis:redis /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
ENV SENTINEL_QUORUM 2
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
ENV SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER 5000
ENV SENTINEL_FAILOVER 10000
ENV SENTINEL_PORT 26000
ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 26379 6379

FROM python:2.7-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
ervices:

  redis-master:
    container_name: redis-master
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --port 6379
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  redis-slave:
    container_name: redis-slave
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --slaveof redis-master 6379 --protected-mode no
    volumes:
       - .:/app

  sentinel-1:
    container_name: sentinel-1
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000

  sentinel-2:
    container_name: sentinel-2
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000

  sentinel-3:
    container_name: sentinel-3
    build: sentinel
    environment:
      - SENTINEL_DOWN_AFTER=5000
      - SENTINEL_FAILOVER=5000
```

Python code I'm trying to run:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='0.0.0.0', port=6379, db=0)
print ("set key1 123")
print (r.set('key1', '123'))
print ("get key1")
print(r.get('key1'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (r.set('key1', '123'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 1519, in set
    return self.execute_command('SET', *pieces)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 836, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1071, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 543, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to 0.0.0.0:6379. Connection refused.
```

I've tried changing host to redis, redis-master, actual Docker IP, some where not found, and some still connection refused.

I've created a network, but then Sentinels couldn't communicate to one another.

I've also tried starting Redis master with configuration file, but error was that it couldn't be found. I did add WORKDIR and COPY to Dockerfile for this purpose.

How can I connect to Redis from Python (also inside Docker)?

Thank you for your time, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to connect from `python` which is in `container` from the same `compose` file:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='redis-master', port=6379, db=0)
```

so you need to use the `service` name

if the `Python` `Container` is not from the same `compose file`, you nned to connect it using the `network` from the redis `compose` and declare it as `external` in your python compose file

Example with `docker run`:

```
docker run -itd --network=MyNetworkFromTheOtherCompose busybox
```

Example with `compose`:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network-FromTheOtherCompose
```